# How to configure Search plugin in Cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I was trying to incorporate Search plugin to my project and I thought I followed the instructions from the download site but whenever I access Posts it gives me these 3 lines of errors:

```
Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PrgComponent' does not have a method 'startup' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 110]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PrgComponent' does not have a method 'beforeRender' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 110]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PrgComponent' does not have a method 'shutdown' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 110]
```

Can someone help me figure this out please?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like either the plugin or your code does not match the 2.0 requirements for valid callbacks. what search plugin version you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download site? Which download site? There is no "download site" for the 2.0 version of this plugin yet.

The 2.0 branch is here https://github.com/CakeDC/search/tree/2.0 and all tests for the PrgComponent pass.

```
9/9 test methods complete: 9 passes, 0 fails, 13 assertions and 0 exceptions.
Time: 0.29582810401917 seconds

Peak memory: 11,688,424 bytes

Run more tests | Show Passes | Analyze Code Coverage

Code coverage results Toggle all files
PrgComponent.php Code coverage: 99.06%
```

Check the 2.0 branch out from git.

Are you even talking about the CakeDC search plugin?

Comment: Hi Burzum, the download site i was talking about was the one from cakedc. It is for 1.3 but not sure if it's going to work with 2.0 but thank you i'll try that link you provided. I'll tag this as the answer to my question. Appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome, in the case you also want to use the 1.3 version, use the master branch on github instead of the download. I think we need to remove the download section, the files there are pretty outdated.

Answer (score 4):

In Cakephp 2.0 component class extents Component not Object

So, write following code:

```
class PrgComponent extends Component {

}
```